# Count switches in a smallest square root sequence mod \$2^n\$

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

#### Definition

For any \$a\equiv1\ (\text{mod }8)\$ and \$n\ge3\$, there are exactly 4 roots to the equation \$x^2\equiv a\ (\text{mod }2^n)\$. Now, let \$x_k(a)\$ be the smallest root to the equation \$x^2\equiv a\ (\text{mod }2^k)\$, then $$\{x_3(a),x_4(a),x_5(a),x_6(a),\cdots\}$$ is a smallest square root sequence (SSRS) of \$a\$ mod \$2^n\$.

[John D. Cook](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/quadratic_congruences/) published a quick algorithm that calculates such roots in \$O(n)\$ time. Assume \$x_k\$ is a root to the equation \$x^2\equiv a\ (\text{mod }2^k)\$. Then, $$x_{k+1}=\begin{cases}x_k&\text{if }\frac{x_k^2-a}{2^k}\text{ is even}\\x_k+2^{k-1}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ 
is a root to the equation \$x^2\equiv a\ (\text{mod }2^{k+1})\$.

Now we define two lists A and B. \$A=\{A_k|k\ge3\}\$ is the list of values generated by the algorithm above with initial values \$A_3=1\$ and \$B=\{B_k|k\ge3\}\$ is the list of values generated with initial values \$B_3=3\$. Each entry in the SSRS \$x_k(a)\$ takes the smallest value among \$A_k\$ and \$B_k\$. We say a switch in SSRS occurs whenever the choice changes from A to B or from B to A.

To illustrate the definition, take \$a=17\$:

[image]

The smallest numbers are highlighted. From the picture there are 13 switches up to mod \$2^{24}\$.

#### Challenge

Write a function or program, that receives 2 integers \$a,\ k\$ as input (where \$a\equiv1\ (\text{mod }8)\$ and \$k\ge3\$) and output how many switches occur in the SSRS of \$a\$ mod \$2^n\$ up to \$n=k\$.

#### Sample I/O

```
1, 3 -> 0
9, 4 -> 1
1, 8 -> 0
9, 16 -> 1
17, 24 -> 13
25, 32 -> 2
33, 40 -> 18
41, 48 -> 17
49, 56 -> 1
1048577, 2048 -> 959
1048585, 2048 -> 970
```

#### Winning Condition

This is a code-golf challenge, so shortest valid submission of each language wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden by default.

Comment: Getting `1048577, 2048 --> 959` with all the other test cases correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: Was this intended to be [restricted-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-complexity)? Otherwise we can just ignore Cook's formula and brute-force the square roots.

Comment: @Noodle9 It is 959 indeed! I have amended the test cases.

Comment: @Grimmy If bruteforcing gives the correct results I will accept it.

Comment: Oh I finally know why I put 1018 in the (1048577, 2048) case. It's actually the result of (17, 2048).

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
LoεLnαy%0k}üÊO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fJ//cVp@8cxsrVQ2yaw/vOdzl//@/kQmXoTkA)

For each `n`, this finds the smallest square root of `a` by brute-force.

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> 23 bytes (fast)

```
13v¹yλ£DnIαN>o%2÷+]@γg<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0Ljs0M7Kc7sPLXbJ8zy30c8uX9Xo8HbtWIdzm9Nt/v83MjCx4DIEEqYWpgA)

This one properly uses Cook's formula.

```
13                    # literal 13
  v               ]   # for each digit:
   ¹                  #  push the input k
    y             ]   #  push the digit
     λ£               #  recurse k times with base case y:
       Dn             #   square of the current value
         Iα           #   absolute difference with input a
           N>o%       #   modulo 2**(N+1)
               2÷     #   integer divide by 2
                 +    #   add to the current value
@                     # compare the two lists element-wise
 γ                    # group consecutive equal elements
  g                   # length
   <                  # -1
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>88</s>  87 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(k)`.

Because of the bitwise operations, this is only guaranteed to work for \$k\le32\$.

```javascript
a=>K=>(x=[p=1,3],F=k=>k<K&&(p^(x=x.map(v=>q=v+=(v*v-a>>k&1)<<k-1),p=x[0]<q))+F(k+1))(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1LDoIwFAD3HoS8Z4FY8Jv0dcmGIxBMGgSjRVrENNy@dmvqdjKZeSqnlu79sJ9sMrfeD@QVyZokrNRY4mnZphVpklrUSQL2Gviav5QFR3Imxwjc1mVKSp1wFEJnHFNLa7NrxYzIKtCMI0KBvjPTYsY@H80dBuAIJeLmF14Q9hEM5vmfyY@xegqnuFAcwqxA9F8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 50 bytes

```
≔⁰ζ⊞υ¹⊞υ³ＦＸ²…³Ｎ«ＵＭυ⁺κ∧﹪÷⁻×κκηι²⊘ιＦ⌕υ⌊υ«≦⊕ζ≔⮌υυ»»Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LasNADDx7v2KPMmyhcQo95BQSSnxwMKE/sPWq8ZJ9hH24kJJv38qJDxUMSBqNRhpGGQYvTSnbGPXZwavgt3rD@hxHyIKv/uVryr994ND7HwzQCH6S7oywFrx115yO2X5Rv6bgv6zq5HXnrZVOzeLe5AgXwbdUdl5l46F1aa8nrRA67Yj91BYfM5da8JGgCQ3hIM2ECvS8ecOqxw0f@rmXpNpmC3lxnW2XV1o3BLToEqrnU1W1MCecMEQkkeB5Ju7szvqgXYKdjAlu5FNK88ZX7@VlMn8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input in the order \$ \small k, a \$. Explanation:

```
≔⁰ζ⊞υ¹⊞υ³
```

Start off with \$ \small 0 \$ swaps and initial values \$ \small A_3 = 1 \$ and \$ \small B_3 = 3 \$ in a list.

```
ＦＸ²…³Ｎ«
```

Loop over the powers of \$ \small 2^n \$ from \$ \small 2^3 \$ to \$ \small 2^{k-1} \$.

```
ＵＭυ⁺κ∧﹪÷⁻×κκηι²⊘ι
```

Map over the list calculating the next values \$ \small A_{n+1} \$ and \$ \small B_{n+1} \$.

```
Ｆ⌕υ⌊υ«
```

Test whether the smallest value is at the start of the list.

```
≦⊕ζ≔⮌υυ
```

If it isn't then increment the number of swaps and reverse the list so that the smallest value is at the start again.

```
»»Ｉζ
```

Print the number of swaps.

I have a <s>48</s> 47 byte version that seems to work on the test cases but I don't know why.

```
≔⁰ζ≔¹δ≔⁰εＦＸ²…³Ｎ«≔﹪÷⁻Ｘδ²ηι²θ≧⁺¬⁼θεζ≔θε≧⁺∧ε⊘ιδ»Ｉζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BCsIwDIbP7ilyTKGCTsGDJ1FBDxvDN6i2boXabms7YeKz145NvBgI5E/4kj@3irU3w1QIO2tlqXFBoSfbZFJLCvyn4kxEdTctYGGeosWUwoXpUuCKwlnX3uX@cY19EgNeyWwCM8O9MnjW7iA7yQVmUns77eAUUkKhiinJWDfxyixj9YhfZFk5LJS3FHLj8Nh4piw2gxsy2v0eakaH/9md5igonJjqBEc5sMNz76RopXa4Z9ZhT8g2hHQNy02Yd@oD) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⁰ζ≔¹δ≔⁰ε
```

Start off with \$ \small 0 \$ swaps, \$ \small A_3 = 1 \$ and \$ \small A_3 < B_3 \$.

```
ＦＸ²…³Ｎ«
```

Loop over the powers of \$ \small 2^n \$ from \$ \small 2^3 \$ to \$ \small 2^{k-1} \$.

```
≔﹪÷⁻Ｘδ²ηι²θ
```

Work out whether \$ \small A_{n+1} > B_{n+1} \$.

```
≧⁺¬⁼θεζ
```

If this is a change from \$ \small A_n > B_n \$ then increment the number of swaps.

```
≔θε
```

Save this for the next loop.

```
≧⁺∧ε⊘ιδ
```

Add \$ \small 2^{n-1} \$ if \$ \small A_{n+1} > B_{n+1} \$.

```
»Ｉζ
```

Print the number of swaps.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
²_⁴ọ2>
R1,3;€¹2*H+ʋ@ç?\€>/IAS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpvhHjVse7u41suMKMtQxtn7UtObQTiMtD@1T3Q6Hl9vHAPl2@p6Owf///zcyMLH4bwgkTC1MAQ)

A full program taking \$n\$ as its left argument and \$k\$ as its right argument. Prints the number of switches.

Will post explanation once have more time to further optimise.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>230</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>180</s></sup> 175 bytes

```python
def f(x,a,k,p=4):
 l=[x]
 for n in range(3,k):x+=p*(((x*x-a)>>n)&1);p*=2;l+=[x]
 return l
def g(a,n):
 i=c=0
 for q in zip(f(1,a,n),f(3,a,n)):j=q[1-i]<q[i];c+=j;i^=j
 return c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBLboMwEIb3nGLEorKTiYR5FAJ1lj1Bd4hKiJjUCXIcQiJaxNmpHaqWrjz/w99Y1p/dx1kF07QXNdSkxxJPqHlIUwcanveFA/W5BQVSQVuqgyABnmjar7leEUL6Vb8p6W6n6BOjmV5xP2vW87VWdLdWQeNY8oGUqCxT8op7M/NimV9Sk5owtDHWBm4Hmh75JWcbWbxccllk1ZofM/nOj7/UatJ8eGtvInXLq4vwWjZXM6tzB0aPjuXfUdgNxAFiFkBAETyKVm0RQqPYrEyW/MvY8yKMEfxHOZgNPzIo3xj@rIPAwDxbSGYjNLzQAln8YxhktER6YRLFlus9ettouwiS6C@IH2@y36ZbqTpSu8M994oRwZysGGGzg@FArIfWoCOQQeeC86VpeqLXourEnrp0@gY)

A function `g` that uses Cook's formula (function `f`).